# Ubuntu 16.04 Python 3.5 bz2 broken

Tags: python

So my Python3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04 is missing bz2(when I try to import bz2 it gives me ImportError). The problem is that both Python3.4 and Python2.7 can import bz2. I've found numerous posts with the same problem and one solution was to install libpython3.5-stdlib which gives me the following error:

```
Setting up python3-pytango (8.1.8-1) ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyTango/tango_gevent.py", line 56
    raise result.error_string, None, result.tb
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package python3-pytango (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-pytango
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I naturally tried to install PyTango for my Python3.5 and it gives me the following error:

```
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -u -c 
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=
'/tmp/pip-build-8aedpxb_/pytango/setup.py';f=
getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-8p527w_d-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8aedpxb_/pytango/
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python3.5` what version is this exactly, and how did you install it? What command did you use when you *"tried to install PyTango for my Python3.5"*?

Comment: @steeldriver it's the version which was installed while dist-update. It's Python 3.5. The command is pip3.5 install pytango

Comment: I don't think a dist-upgrade would install anything in /usr/local/

Comment: @steeldriver well I had Python 3.5 which I downloaded from official site before update. Could that be it? It would be strange because 16.04 is pretty much tied to 3.5.

Comment: If you downloaded and installed a version from outside of the repository, (and not using a virtualenv) then yes that might explain your issues. Perhaps the significance of the dist-upgrade is just that before it, the local version was the same as the system version, and now it isn't?

Comment: @steeldriver in my previous system version Python 3.4 was used so I had to install Python 3.5. And in 16.04 system version is 3.5. Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48832/discussion-between-steeldriver-and-upmostscarab).

Comment: @steeldriver: There was an update in the chat but OP forgot to ping you.

Answer (score -2):

remove python3-pytango with this:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pytango
```

then remove the existing dependency

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

May be a solution.
It's like I've ever experienced

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what this does and why. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)